# Keep Window Manager views after service destroy

Tags: android, android-layout, android-service

I'm making a floating view above all apps, but everytime the service I use to add the view to window manager crashes, (due to memory issues on device or whatever) the view gets removed. I return START_STICKY so that it is added immediately again, but is there any way to keep it on screen because the flicker isn't very appealing.

**Code onStartCommand()**

```
final ImageView container = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            SettingsUtil.getFloaterSize(), WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                    + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE + WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).addView(container, params);
```

`

Comment: put some code and error log as well if you expect any answer.

Comment: I do't get any errors it's just the android system periodically stopping my service like in case it needs memory. I'm just wondering how you can keep window manager views on it if it's possible.

Comment: service isn't related to your window. a service might stops or starts no matter what's the status of activities.

Comment: So then why when my service is stopped all the views in my window are removed?

Comment: what are you trying to do with that code?

Comment: I'm making like a facebook chathead sort of view that sticks around over the screen. The problem is, it disapears when the service is destroyed by the OS, is there a way to keep the views on the screen regardless?

Comment: Essentially, I want to add a view to window manager that can stay attached even if the service stops. Is there any way to bind it permanently to the screen, or preventing the service from stopping or something?

Comment: then how your window gonna end working?

Comment: Idk like is there a way to put a view in window manager for an indefinite amount of time. Because with a service, it can stop at any given moment.

Comment: I think that was impossible. Ask another question about this issue or update this one to get other's solutions/answers.